# *ngIf & Jquery acting weird - Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use expand-collapse feature of bootstrap 4 and was encountering a weird issue with the use of *ngIf for expansion and collapse.
Whenever I try to use *ngIf as follows, the jquery doesn't work but works when *ngIf is deleted.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="collapse-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7" id="row">
            <div id="link_text_div" *ngIf="this.collapseExpandArrowFlag==true">
          <span   id="collapse_all" class="close-button" (click)="arrowFunc($event)" style="cursor: pointer;" >
            Collapse all
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id="link_text_div" *ngIf="this.collapseExpandArrowFlag==false">
          <span  id="expand_all" class="open-button" (click)="arrowFunc($event)" style="cursor: pointer;"
         >
            Expand all
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**.Ts:**

```
collapseExpandArrowFlag = true;


  arrowFunc(event) {
if(event.srcElement.id === "collapse_all") {   //On-Click Collapse Logic

      this.collapseExpandArrowFlag = false;

      $(".close-button").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.multi-collapse').collapse('hide');
      });

    }


  if(event.srcElement.id === "expand_all") {      
      this.collapseExpandArrowFlag = true;

      $(".open-button").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.multi-collapse').collapse('show');
      });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "this" in the ngIf like this:

```
 *ngIf="collapseExpandArrowFlag==true"
```

Comment: Tried, no luck!

Comment: try:  *ngIf="collapseExpandArrowFlag" and *ngIf="!collapseExpandArrowFlag"

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the 'this.' from the *ngIf and just write

```
*ngIf="collapseExpandArrowFlag"
```

If this not working , try to change *ngIf to

```
[hidden]="collapseExpandArrowFlag"
```

and

```
[hidden]="!collapseExpandArrowFlag"
```

This will add the element and the event on the dom on load time. and will keep it there (with a display : none property in css).

Plus take into consideration how you need to work with external library code like JQuery.

See references:

[Use jQuery script with Angular 6 CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629951/use-jquery-script-with-angular-6-cli-project/51630120#51630120)

Comment: Edited my comment.

Comment: using [hidden] is not displaying any clickable link on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Change you ts file as follows

```
collapseExpandArrowFlag = true;

arrowFunc(event) {
if(event.srcElement.id === "collapse_all") {   //On-Click Collapse Logic

  this.collapseExpandArrowFlag = false;

  $(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.multi-collapse').collapse('hide');

}


if(event.srcElement.id === "expand_all") {      
  this.collapseExpandArrowFlag = true;

  $(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.multi-collapse').collapse('show');

}
```

What's happening here is, when you click the button, inside ts code,

```
  this.collapseExpandArrowFlag = false;
```

is called, and in the template the `close-button` is removed.

But in the very next line of ts code,

```
 $(".close-button")
```

is called, But in this state that element is removed from the DOM

And make sure you've removed  `this.` from `*ngIf` statements

Comment: I also had thought regarding same, the thing is even If I move the flagcode to the line after the jquery, it still doesn't work and what you proposed also got no luck :(

Comment: Then that would be because ` $(this)` is not referring the DOM element we want. Instead of `$(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.multi-collapse').collapse('hide');` just try to use `$('.collapse-group').find('.multi-collapse').collapse('hide');` . If it works, then use most suitable jquery selector afterwards